# Powershell If statement with multiple conditions

Tags: powershell, if-statement, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

I have a Powershell script with If statement and multiple conditions. My code is working great but I am looking for to display which condition my object doesn't respect.

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory -Force | ForEach-Object {

$FolderName = $_.BaseName -match $Folderpattern
$DateOK = $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3))
$Folder = $_.BaseName
    
if (($FolderName) -and ($DateOK) {
                write-host("$Folder can be moved") 
            }
            else {
                write-host("$Folder can't be moved")
            }
        }
```

I would like to display "$folder can't be moved because it doesn't match the pattern" if it doesn't respect the $FolderName condition.

And display "$folder can't be moved because the last write time is less than 3 days" if it doesn't respect the $DateOK condition.

thanks for the help

Comment: What should it say if _both_ conditions fail?

Comment: There's a lot of ways to approach this solution (e.g. we could suggest `switch` with a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-switch?view=powershell-7.2#scriptblock)); but the cleanest from a code perspective (IMO) is to create a custom function to replace your ForEach loop, have it accept pipeline input, then in the `process` block include guard clauses (see https://www.foxdeploy.com/blog/got-messy-ifs-guard-clauses-to-the-rescue.html for some examples - only use `return` instead of `throw` given the context is a loop)

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis in the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to go about this; but this one is clean and easy to understand, so would be my preferred route:

```
Function Move-FolderConditional { # todo: give this cmdlet a better name for your context
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]]$Path
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Destination
        ,
        # files matching this pattern get moved to the target
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$ArchivableFolderPattern
        ,
        # Files older than this date get moved to the target
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$MinKeepDateUtc = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3).ToUniversalTime()
    )
    Process {
        foreach ($directory in $Path) {
            if ($directory.BaseName -notmatch $ArchivableFolderPattern) {
                Write-Warning "Could not move folder '$($directory.FullName)' as the name does not match the required pattern"
                continue;
            }
            if ($directory.LastWriteTimeUtc -ge $MinKeepDateUtc) {
                Write-Warning "Could not archive folder '$($directory.FullName)' as it was last updated at '$($directory.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString('u'))'"
                continue;
            }
            try {
                #Move-Item -Path $directory -Destination $Destination -ErrorAction Stop # Uncommend this if you actually want to move your files
                Write-Information "Successfully moved '$($directory.FullName)' to '$($Destination.FullName)'" 
            } catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] { # For this exception we'd probably check in the Begin block instead - but this is just to give the idea that we could add a try/catch if required
                Write-Warning "Could not archive folder '$($directory.FullName)' the target directory does not exist: '$($Destination.FullName)'"
            }  
        }
    }
}

# Example usage
Get-ChildItem $path -Directory -Force | Move-FolderConditional -ArchivableFolderPattern '^log' -InformationAction Continue -Destination 'z:\archive\'
```

But other options are available (I've just included snippets to give the gist of these):

### Switch Statement

```
switch ( $directory )
{
    {$_.BaseName -notmatch $ArchivableFolderPattern}
    {
        Write-Warning "Could not move folder '$($_.FullName)' as the name does not match the required pattern"
        break
    }
    {$_.LastWriteTimeUtc -ge $MinKeepDateUtc}
    {
        Write-Warning "Could not archive folder '$($_.FullName)' as it was last updated at '$($_.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString('u'))'"
        break
    }
    default 
    {
        Write-Information "Successfully moved '$($_.FullName)' to '$($Destination.FullName)'" 
    }
}
```

### Flags

```
[bool]$archiveFolder = $true
if ($directory.BaseName -notmatch $ArchivableFolderPattern) {
    Write-Warning "Could not move folder '$($directory.FullName)' as the name does not match the required pattern"
    $archiveFolder = $false
}
if ($directory.LastWriteTimeUtc -ge $MinKeepDateUtc) { 
    # note: this will process even if archivefolder is already false... you can use `else` or amend the condition to include `$archiveFolder -or ($directory.LastWriteTimeUtc -ge $MinKeepDateUtc)`; though if going that route it's better to use the switch statement.
    Write-Warning "Could not archive folder '$($directory.FullName)' as it was last updated at '$($_.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString('u'))'"
    $archiveFolder = $false
}
if ($archiveFolder) {
    Write-Information "Successfully moved '$($directory.FullName)' to '$($Destination.FullName)'" 
}
```

### Other

Or you can do combinations of the above (e.g. use the switch statement to set your flags (in which case you can optionally remove the `break` so that all issues are displayed).

Comment: The `switch` looks very clean, especially if you want to output all issues.

Comment: Indeed - though the switch above wouldn't output all issues - to do that you'd have to replace `break` with `$archiveFolder=$false` / mix in some of the other logic from the Flags example.

Comment: In PowerShell, `switch` enters all matching "case" branches, unless there is a `break`, so just removing the `break` should output all issues.

Comment: @zett42 ah good point; I was thinking it would still process the `default` block; but you're right; if 1 or more cases are matched the default isn't used regardless of breaks (it's not a feature I use often, so had to test that to check).  Thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 3):

If this is just for checking and not for keeping a log where you need those specific messages I might go for something simple where we just capture the true and false values for each of the tests.

```
$path = C:\temp
Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory -Force |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Folder         = $_.BaseName
            LastWriteTime  = $_.LastWriteTime
            FolderNameTest = $_.BaseName -match 'test'
            DateOKTest     = $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
        }
    }
```

Sample Output

```
Folder         LastWriteTime       FolderNameTest DateOKTest
------         -------------       -------------- ----------
.git           06.09.2021 01:06:06          False       True
.vscode        25.09.2021 10:06:11          False       True
1              22.09.2021 22:30:26          False       True
batch_test     02.05.2022 22:29:25           True      False
cleanup        20.09.2021 10:02:51          False       True
DeviceDatabase 26.09.2021 12:07:26          False       True
host           22.09.2021 23:23:38          False       True
move_logs      26.04.2022 19:28:59          False      False
test_run       01.03.2022 22:14:14           True       True
```

You can then pipe this to `Export-Csv` if you like